# Error using ASP.NET Core and EF Core with SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

When I try to access a view to load data from my SQL Server 2008 R2 database (using ASP.NET Core 2.2 with EF Core 2.2), I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'. Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

Here's my get list from repository:

```
    public IEnumerable<Vessel> Listar(Vessel vessel, ref Pagination pagination)
    {
        pagination.Records = _SOOContext.Vessel.AsQueryable()
            .Where(r => (vessel == null || vessel.VesselId == 0 || r.VesselId == vessel.VesselId))
            .Where(r => vessel == null || vessel.VesselCallSign == null || (vessel.VesselCallSign.StartsWith("%") && r.VesselCallSign.Contains(vessel.VesselCallSign.Remove(0, 1))) | r.VesselCallSign.StartsWith(vessel.VesselCallSign))
            .Where(r => vessel == null || vessel.VesselName == null || (vessel.VesselName.StartsWith("%") && r.VesselName.Contains(vessel.VesselName.Remove(0, 1))) | r.VesselName.StartsWith(vessel.VesselName))
            .Count();

        pagination.CalcPages();

        string orderby = pagination.OrderBy;

        var conexaoEF = _SOOContext.Vessel
            .Where(r => (vessel == null || vessel.VesselId == 0 || r.VesselId == vessel.VesselId))
            .Where(r => vessel == null || vessel.VesselCallSign == null || (vessel.VesselCallSign.StartsWith("%") && r.VesselCallSign.Contains(vessel.VesselCallSign.Remove(0, 1))) | r.VesselCallSign.StartsWith(vessel.VesselCallSign))
            .Where(r => vessel == null || vessel.VesselName == null || (vessel.VesselName.StartsWith("%") && r.VesselName.Contains(vessel.VesselName.Remove(0, 1))) | r.VesselName.StartsWith(vessel.VesselName))
            .OrderBy(p => p.VesselCallSign)
            .Skip(pagination.SkipRecords)
            .Take(pagination.PageSize);

        return conexaoEF.ToList();
    }
```

In `Startup.cs` I've inserted the following command lines:

```
var connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SOO;Integrated Security=True";

services.AddDbContext<SOOContext>(options => options
                .UseSqlServer(connectionString, builder => builder.UseRowNumberForPaging()));
```

Comment: There's a workaround in the linked duplicate - `UseRowNumberForPaging` - but note that you may not be able to use net core 3 with SQL 2008 - https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/16400

Comment: [UseRowNumberForPaging - Use a ROW_NUMBER() in queries instead of OFFSET/FETCH. This method is backwards-compatible to SQL Server 2005.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.sqlserverdbcontextoptionsbuilder.userownumberforpaging?view=efcore-2.2)